# Creating react project using create-react-app fails with strange error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a React project using `create-react-app` and it is showing a strange error.

Here is the image of the error.

[Install Cmd Code Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3TPo.png)  -  [Node Version Image Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJWbB.png)

I changed node version, cleared the cache and tried again. But still same error occurs.

I would be really grateful for any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go through the DOC once. "https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html .

Answer (score 1):

You should write `npx create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have installed `create-react-app` globally.

I guess that you must installed it using `npm install -g create-react-app`.

And remember that `create-react-app` should not be globally installed. Take a look at their [official site](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start).

Got it? Crystal clear, then.

Remove the installed one using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.
And use `npx create-react-app` instead of `create-react-app`.

For your case, `npx create-react-app testing`.